# Accessors behavior in c# is doubtful

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, properties, field

Is the declaration

```
public string FirstName;
```

equivalent to

```
public string FirstName { get; set;}
```

I believe there is no difference, but I found the following: when I created a model - something like this

```
public class Subject
{
    public string SubjectName;// { get; set; }
}
```

and then posted this object using form in MVC, I get `SubjectName` value `null`. But if I remove commented accessors then I get a value. Is there any reason for such behavior?

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan possibly but this seems to be more as to how Fields and Properties relate to MVC

Comment: it's about MVC models and POST method i guess

Comment: @BSoD_ZA Since the OP asked *Is below code is equivalent...I believe there is no difference, but...* I think this questions implies *What's the difference between these two code variants*. Also, the OP knows already that fields will not work when using the MVC framework, only properties.

Comment: @xi-huan i just want to know why fields don't work in MVC and Wpf apps. what is special in Properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two are certainly *not* equivalent.

```
public string FirstName;

public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

The first is a typical [*field*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), just like a plain-old C++ `class` member.

The second is a [*property*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).  More specifically it is an [auto-implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384054.aspx).  Properties are essentially just syntactic sugar for `_get()` and `_set(value)` functions, like one would be used to in Java.  Auto-implemented properties take it a step further and hide the *backing field* where the data is saved for you.

Since you're *supposed* to use properties, and not fields, for your public API, many .NET frameworks/APIs like [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc), [EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907), etc. will do *special* things with the properties of a class (for example automatically create a database schema).

Why are you supposed to use properties?  Consider the following example.  You have a plain-jane class, with an auto-implemented property.

```
public class Foo {
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And you have some client code:

```
var f = Foo();
f.Bar = 32;
```

Let's say you want to add an event that fires when you change something in `Foo`.  Since you used a property, you can simply change the implementation:

```
public class Foo {
    private int m_bar;
    public int Bar {
        get { return m_bar; }
        set {
            m_bar = value;
            OnChanged();
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler Changed;
    protected virtual void OnChanged() {
        var evt = Changed;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

and (*the important part!*) the client-facing API stays the same.  This is just one example of how properties are definitely the "right choice".

Comment: thanks now i need to find those special things about properties :)

Comment: @Arun Unfortunately I'm not terribly familiar with how MVC handles properties specially. In Entity Framework, you can use [code first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx) to generate your database from your objects.

Comment: that i ll' do at my end. thanks all roads

Answer (score 5):

It's not equivalent code. There is big difference - without accessors you have public [**field**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173118.aspx), with accessors you have auto-implemented [**property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384054.aspx). MVC, WPF, Entitiy Framework etc needs properties (in MVC default model binder works only with properties). See [Properties vs Fields – Why Does it Matter?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Field

```
public string SubjectName;
```

Property

```
public string SubjectName { get; set; }
```

Both are serving the same value but they are different.